# JDK 1.6.0 update 45 does not install the "Public JRE" - why?

Tags: java

I was trying to upgrade Java 1.6.0 to the latest update 45. I first uninstalled the previous version (update 43), but this time for some odd reason the JDK installer (jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe) does not install the "Public JRE" as it normally does along with the JDK. It does not even list it as options (it only shows Development Tools and Source Code, but does not list "Public JRE").

When I thus subsequently tried to install the JRE separately (using jre-6u45-windows-i586.exe), I got the message that the JRE was already installed.

So, for some odd reason the JDK installer (as well as the JRE-installer) seem to believe that JRE 1.6.0 update 45 is already installed while it is NOT.

Any idea, how to convince it otherwise?

This is on Windows 7 (x64 Enterprise) and with the 32-bit Java version (the 64 bit version installed fine as usual. I need both versions for test purposes just to avoid that question...)

Comment: Do you have a jre folder inside your java_home folder?

Comment: Maybe this is another security initiative by Oracle.  Some people want to develop with older versions of Java but don't necessarily want the older version acting as a browser plugin, which is what the public jre installer will do. Just run the public jre installer manually alongside your jdk install.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a loss to understand what your problem is.  The JDK install includes all of the tools and libraries that a JRE install contains.  Add the `bin` subdirectory on your shell's PATH environment variable and both the JRE tools and the other tools can be used.

Comment: actually, traditionally the jdk installer kicked the jre installer, not sure how this works in the last version of jdk6